# SQL code that will confirm that 2 columns of a table is 'synchronized', if not flag it

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I'm having a bit of trouble writing an sql for this scenario.

For example given a table (this is just to simplify and mask the actual data...), ContactInfo, it has 2 columns Address and Phone. I would like to write an sql that will confirm that given an address, the phone will always be the same for that address (hence 'synchronized') and if they are not, flag it:

[image]

So in this example if person Abc and Def have same address, their phone should be same as well (ie only one landline phone number in a resident) and that person Klm should be flagged as he lives in same unit but has different phone.

***The table is denormalized but that's how it is, normalizing is not an option...

This is for Sybase 12.5 ASE.

Comment: sorry about that, I've now added the database product and the version being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

You could try this

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM ContactInfo a
  INNER JOIN ContactInfo b on a.address = b.address
WHERE a.phone != b.phone
```

Some SQL's prefer `<>` to `!=`

This will get you any records that match address but don't match phone number.  So it will show Abc & KLM and DEF and Klm  (but not Abc & Def).

You can't tell which is **right** here - perhaps Klm is the correct phone number and both abc and def have moved on. Or maybe Klm has a mobile phone.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that there is no indication of which phone number is right.  As an aside, OP, you will probably want to use the {distinct} keyword with this query so you don't get duplicate results (ex. abc & klm, def & klm, klm & abc, klm & def).

Comment: Another thing, Sybase ASE is case sensitive. The table columns that are in the question don't match the ones that you put in your answer (ex: address != Address)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to give the incorrect address only, like this:

```
SELECT distinct a.Address
FROM ContactInfo a
  INNER JOIN ContactInfo b on a.Address = b.Address
WHERE a.Phone != b.Phone
```